# What does the Gamma means in local ringed space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, self-learning

I found the following problem from an algebraic geometry course hold in 2003.

Let $(X,\mathscr A)$ locally ringed space and $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathscr A)$. Prove that $$X_f=\{x\in X|f(x)\ne 0\}$$ is an open subset of $X$.

What does the $\Gamma$ means in this context, or is is some course-specific notation?

Comment: It means global sections of ${\mathscr A}$, i.e. $\Gamma(X,{\mathscr A}) := {\mathscr A}(X)$.

Comment: It is standard notation

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213116, https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3475